# Hadoop 3.0.3 -- Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password)

Tags: hadoop, ssh

Another episode of the dreaded SSH fail...seems awfully common!

I'm installing Hadoop 3.0.3 on a cluster of 3 servers -- A, B, and C.
A is the Namenode, B and C are workers.
Each server can contact the other two servers using SSH
without a password.  Permissions for the .ssh directory are
at 700 on each machine, and permissions for the authorized_keys
are at 600 on each machine.  Good for me.

Regardless -- attempting to run start-dfs.sh or start-all.sh
throws the message:
A: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
(A -- for server A)

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

In addition to setting up SSH between
all pairs of machines -- I had to configure
SSH from each machine to itself.

I'd love to know exactly why this was necessary,
can only guess that multiple processes on the same
machine are trying to communicate...